# Returning multiple values independently from django model for modelchoicefield

Tags: python, django

I have a model called group and another called group membership. What I'm trying to do is return a seperate string, for one of my fields in my form.
It displays correctly in the front end but when writing to the database it's all in one string. All im trying to do is get the group_name and cut out the rest of the string when writing to the database.
I'm aiming for a way to return more then one value, because i need to grab company and department later on from that same model.

My Model

```
# Group #
#########
class Group(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='group_created_by')
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
            related_name='group_modified_by',
            blank=True, null=True)

    def create(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}{}{}'.format(self.company, self.department, self.group_name)
```

My Form

```
# Group Name #
##############
class GroupNameModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return '{}'.format(obj.group_name)


# Group Membership #
####################
class GroupMembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    options = (('Enabled', 'Enabled',), ('Disabled', 'Disabled'))
    member_id = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            )
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Company.objects.filter(status='Enabled'),
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            empty_label=''
            )
    department = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Department.objects.filter(status='Enabled'),
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            empty_label=''
            )
    group_name = GroupNameModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Group.objects.filter(status='Enabled'),
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            empty_label=''
            )
    user_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Person.objects.filter(status='Enabled'),
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            empty_label=''
            )
    full_name = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            )
    status = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'},
                choices=options
                )
            )

    class Meta:
        model = GroupMembership
        fields = ('member_id', 'company', 'department', 'group_name',
                'user_id', 'full_name', 'status')
```

Comment: Looking at the code it looks like the guilty part is the `__str__` method. But to make your question clear can you add what you send, what you expect and what you see?

Comment: for example ill send for the group name Western Region, but what gets written to the database is ABC Pipeline INC Engineering Services Western Region. I just need to write western region.

Comment: Very very likely, the return value of `__str__` method is getting written. If you are using the `__str__` method's value for admin view, there are better ways to do it. Keep `__str__` to return a single value like `group_name`. If you confirm the solution, I will give you links to the better ways I talked about (I am saying the if because I dont want to unnecessarily talk about it :) )

Comment: I'm sort of aiming for a way to return more then one value, because i need to grab company and department later on from that same model.

Comment: So far, every time I did that, I got into trouble with various issues. I started liking @property method of getting special values. Little mode code, so adding an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Group #
#########
class Group(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='group_created_by')
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
            related_name='group_modified_by',
            blank=True, null=True)

    def create(self):
        self.save()

    # Please rename to something sensible
    @property
    def get_special_combination_value(self):
        return '{}{}{}'.format(self.company, self.department, self.group_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name
```

To use the `@property`:

```
from <yourapp>.models import Group

obj = Group()
# following line will print the special string
obj.get_special_combination_value
```

The property value can also be used in django admin as:

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_special_combination_value',)

admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```